# What is this control called?

Tags: terminology

http://www.jsfiddle.net/FxCdE/

I'm looking for the name of this control.  It's two lists with buttons to move items from one list to another list.   usually this is used to create a large set from a large set of data. It is often coupled with filters for the list which represents the "selectable" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft call them ["List builders"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511484.aspx).

Comment: This is an authoritative source so I will count this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is a `list shuttle`, but I am not sure that there is only one terminology for it.

On my project, I use Richfaces as a JSF components library, and there is such a component, called [list shuttle](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/listShuttle.jsf).

Comment: I like this name.  It's descriptive and google comes up with results for it.   I'll wait and see if anyone else has some good suggestions before accepting though.

Answer (score 0):

I've always called it a "two-pane selection".